# Boostrap 4 menu background color on phone

Tags: bootstrap-4, navbar

I have problems with bootstrap 4 navbar, I would like to change background color on phone (only where are links placed), header would be blue.

***HTML code:***

```
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top ">
  <div class="container"> <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-logo mx-auto">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="index.php"><img src="logo.svg" class="img-fluid logo"/></a>
  </li>
</ul>        <button class="navbar-toggler order-first" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" >
      <span class="custom-toggler navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#">link1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#">link2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

***EXAMPLE how would I like to have it***

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Post the CSS too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.navbar-collapse {
background: #333;
margin: -.5rem -1rem;
padding: .5rem 1rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .navbar-collapse {
    background: #eeefef;
  }
}
```

Depending on the width where the menu can be toggled, you should change the `max-width` property.